# php session_start() changing value of a numeric variable from ajax/jquery call

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a weird issue where for some reason something related to `session_start()` in php is changing the value of a numeric value in a variable from any number (in this case 131, but does it with any number) to 1 from a form select.

**HTML**

```
<select id="findcity">
    <option value="130">this</option>
    <option value="131">that</option>
    <option value="132">another</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_0">button</button>
```

In this case I am selecting option #2 with value 131

**My jquery**

```
$('#box_0').on('click','#btn_0',function() {
    var findcity = $('#findcity').val();
    alert(findcity);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/addfindcity.php?",
        data: "findcity="+ findcity,
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
});
```

If I place an `alert(findcity)` after `var findcity = $('#findcity').val();` the value it retrieves from my select is correct which is the number `131`

If I place the `alert(data)` in the success from the ajax callback the value returned in `1`. Example...

```
$('#box_0').on('click','#btn_0',function() {
    var findcity = $('#findcity').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/addfindcity.php?",
        data: "findcity="+ findcity,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

So of course I go to my php file `addfindcity.php` and see what's going on there.

Here is my php file

**addfindcity.php**

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION['findcity'] = $findcity;
?>
```

If I `echo` back the value it comes back `1`

```
<?
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['findcity'] = $findcity;
?>
```

but... if I echo back the value **before** `session_start()` then the value is correct and still remains at `131` like this

```
<?
echo $findcity;
session_start();
$_SESSION['findcity'] = $findcity;
?>
```

I am not sure why something with saving the numeric value to a session is changing it to `1`. I have several other scripts that do the same thing with none numeric values that work fine. It seems that this one that is numeric only does this. Any ideas?

Comment: use `$_POST['findcity']` to get `findcity` value

Comment: Hey..Mate..Do you even don't know how how to retrieve posted values as I can clearly see you are retrieving session instead of retrieving posted values..! :D

Comment: lol @GarvitMangal that worked, what's weird is that I do that same code for none numeric values and they come back fine. Please make your comment an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai yes I do know about how to retrieve posted values with `$_POST` but I have `global_variables` ON which I know is a security risk, but I can't change it so I have the convenience of being able to use the none posted variable version. What I don't understand is why a numeric value does not work, while a none numeric value does.

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai you should brush up on your grammar. And It's not shared hosting.

Comment: @CesarBielich : Ahaa...Seems like I hurt your feelings..! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this

JS

```
    $('#box_0').on('click','#btn_0',function() {
    var findcity = $('#findcity').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/addfindcity.php",
        data: "findcity="+ findcity,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
 <?php
session_start();
$_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_SESSION['findcity'] = $_POST["findcity"];
?>
```